# Cannot submit form with client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I am using client_side_validations in order to display validations in a continuous way. These validations work but when I click on "submit", nothing happens.

Here is my code :

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
....
<%= f.submit "Inscription" %>
<% end %>
```

**client_side_validations.rb**

```
# ClientSideValidations Initializer

# Uncomment to disable uniqueness validator, possible security issue
# ClientSideValidations::Config.disabled_validators = [:uniqueness]

# Uncomment to validate number format with current I18n locale
# ClientSideValidations::Config.number_format_with_locale = true

# Uncomment the following block if you want each input field to have the validation messages attached.

# Note: client_side_validation requires the error to be encapsulated within
# <label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message"></label>

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

I also added `//= require rails.validations` in my application.js

Thank you in advance !

Comment: No action on submit means there is some validation error. The errors will only be printed if you are using <label> tags in your form.

Comment: Right ! Thank you, however there is a trouble remaining : my password validations are not displayed. Yet I put a label just before the password and password confirmation.